How to log to my system using python logging
foo.py:
#!/usr/bin/python3
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format='[%(levelname)s] %(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

logger.info('foo')

I run python3 foo.py yet journalctl -f doesn't show foo. What am I missing?
P.S. $ logger xyz works
